# Issue with sonar-pmd-plugin for sonarqube5.5

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.5

I'm gettingbelow error when im trying to install pmd plugin in SonarQube5.5. Installation is successfull if I remove the plugin from extensions/plugins.
    Can anyone advice what could be doneto resolve the same.
    Thanks.

```
2016.05.18 16:30:15 INFO  ce[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSyst`enter code here`em] SonarQube home: C:\ATT\sonarqube-5.5
2016.05.18 16:30:16 INFO  ce[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1463569153699] loaded [], sites []
2016.05.18 16:30:19 INFO  ce[o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Load plugins
2016.05.18 16:30:20 ERROR ce[o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine startup failed
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.sonar.core.platform.PluginLoader.basePluginKey(PluginLoader.java:176) ~[sonar-core-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.PluginLoader.defineClassloaders(PluginLoader.java:85) ~[sonar-core-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.PluginLoader.load(PluginLoader.java:71) ~[sonar-core-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.ce.container.CePluginRepository.start(CePluginRepository.java:71) ~[sonar-ce-5.5.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$1.start(ComponentContainer.java:320) ~[sonar-core-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:141) ~[sonar-core-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.ce.container.ComputeEngineContainerImpl.start(ComputeEngineContainerImpl.java:605) ~[sonar-ce-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.ce.ComputeEngineImpl.startup(ComputeEngineImpl.java:43) ~[sonar-ce-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer$CeMainThread.startup(CeServer.java:176) [sonar-ce-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer$CeMainThread.attemptStartup(CeServer.java:166) [sonar-ce-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer$CeMainThread.run(CeServer.java:154) [sonar-ce-5.5.jar:na]
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=160m; support was removed in 8.0
```

When Im Using sonar-pmd 2.5 without changes, below is the error:

```
2016.05.19 16:26:20 ERROR web[o.s.s.p.Platform] Fail to stop server - ignored
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot stop.  Current container state was: CONSTRUCTED
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleState.stopping(DefaultLifecycleState.java:72) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.stop(DefaultPicoContainer.java:794) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.stop(DefaultPicoContainer.java:799) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.stop(DefaultPicoContainer.java:799) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.stopComponents(ComponentContainer.java:173) ~[sonar-core-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.stopComponents(ComponentContainer.java:168) ~[sonar-core-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.stop(PlatformLevel.java:93) ~[sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.stopLevel234Containers(Platform.java:240) ~[sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStop(Platform.java:269) ~[sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.stopQuietly(PlatformServletContextListener.java:59) [sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:52) [sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
2016.05.19 16:26:20 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to load plugin PMD [pmd]
    at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerExtensionInstaller.installExtensions(ServerExtensionInstaller.java:74) ~[sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel4.start(PlatformLevel4.java:687) ~[sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:216) ~[sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:190) ~[sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:113) ~[sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:99) ~[sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:44) ~[sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
    at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerExtensionInstaller.installExtensions(ServerExtensionInstaller.java:64) ~[sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
... 15 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Which version of PMD plugin are you deploying? 
Note that version 2.5 of SonarQube PMD plugin [is recommended](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+version+matrix) version for SonarQube 5.5.

Comment: Please add more information; e.g. operating system, version of PMD, etc.

Comment: Im using customized plugin which is working fine in SonarQube4.5 and Operationg System is Window7 64 bit, If I use 2.5 of SonarQube PMD with out any changes, then i'm getting below error which is different from earlier